# Find missing numbers in a sorted column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, tidyverse

I have this dataframe below and I want to detect missing Visits for each subject, how can I sort the visits by Subject and extract only the records that has missing values ? Please check the two type of output needed.

Part 1 : So depending on the highest number in the Column "Visit" for all Subjects missing records for all subjects needs to show up :

```
    Subject  Visit      X1      X2
       A       1    1647143  1672244
       A       2    1672244  1689707
       A       4    1689707  1713090
       B       1    1735352  1760283
       B       2    1760283  1788062
       B       7    1788062  1789885
       B       9    1789885  1790728
```

The output would be :

```
    Subject  Visit      X1      X2
       A       3    1647143  1672244
       A       5    1672244  1689707
       A       6    1689707  1713090
       A       7    1647143  1672244
       A       8    1672244  1689707
       A       9    1689707  1713090
       B       3    1735352  1760283
       B       4    1760283  1788062
       B       5    1788062  1789885
       B       6    1789885  1790728
       B       8    1789885  1790728
```

Part 2 : So depending on the highest number in the Column "Visit" for each specific Subject missing records in the Sequence of visits needs to show up :
Example Output :

```
    Subject  Visit      X1      X2
       A       3    1647143  1672244
       B       3    1735352  1760283
       B       4    1760283  1788062
       B       5    1788062  1789885
       B       6    1789885  1790728
       B       8    1789885  1790728
```

Comment: Can you please share s sample output of the above mentioned dataframe

Comment: @Devarshi Mandal   Please take a look , I just did

Comment: What is the requirement to fill X1 and X2 in the outcome?

Comment: No need to look at X1 and X2 Jorge

Comment: When you create the missing row, where is the row data and X1 and X2 are coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find the missing visits for each subject, where the max visit per subject is the max of the `Visit` column, you can create the set of all possible `(subject, visit)` pairs, and then difference the observed pairs.

```
from itertools import product

all_pairs = set(product(sorted(set(df.Subject)), range(1, df.Visit.max()+1)))
observed_pairs = set(tuple(x) for x in df[['Subject', 'Visit']].to_numpy())

# create a data frame from the missing pairs
pd.DataFrame(sorted(all_pairs.difference(observed_pairs)), columns=['Subject', 'Visit'])
# returns:
   Subject  Visit
0        A      3
1        A      5
2        A      6
3        A      7
4        A      8
5        A      9
6        B      3
7        B      4
8        B      5
9        B      6
10       B      8
```

To find the missing visit within the max visit range per subject.  You can do the following:

```
def missing_visits(s):
    all_v = set(range(1, s.max()+1))
    obs_v = set(s)
    return sorted(all_v.difference(obs_v))


df.groupby('Subject')['Visit'].apply(missing_visits).explode()
# returns:
Subject
A    3
B    3
B    4
B    5
B    6
B    8
```

Comment: the subjects are not only A and B, the result dataframe from your code shows only A and B Subjects

Answer (score 1):

```
 #Use the min, max in the visit column for each group to reindex df and fillna
    g=df.groupby('Subject',group_keys=False).apply(lambda x:x.reindex(np.arange(x['Visit'].min(),x['Visit'].max())).ffill().bfill())

#Update the visit column
g['Visit']=g.index

print(g)
# First outcome



Subject  Visit         X1         X2
1       A      1  1672244.0  1689707.0
2       A      2  1689707.0  1713090.0
3       A      3  1689707.0  1713090.0
1       B      1  1735352.0  1760283.0
2       B      2  1735352.0  1760283.0
3       B      3  1735352.0  1760283.0
4       B      4  1760283.0  1788062.0
5       B      5  1788062.0  1789885.0
6       B      6  1789885.0  1790728.0
7       B      7  1789885.0  1790728.0
8       B      8  1789885.0  1790728.0


#Filtered outcome

    #Create and compare tuples of ['Subject','Visit'] of the original and new dataframes
g[~g[['Subject','Visit']].agg(tuple,1).isin(df[['Subject','Visit']].agg(tuple,1))]



    Subject  Visit    X1         X2
3       A      3  1689707.0  1713090.0
3       B      3  1735352.0  1760283.0
4       B      4  1760283.0  1788062.0
5       B      5  1788062.0  1789885.0
6       B      6  1789885.0  1790728.0
8       B      8  1789885.0  1790728.0
```

Comment: @Shahine Greene, does this help? Happy to assist further

Answer (score 1):

Here are `data.table` options in `R`

- Part1

```
> setDT(df)[, .(Visit = setdiff(seq(max(df[, "Visit"])), Visit)), Subject]
    Subject Visit
 1:       A     3
 2:       A     5
 3:       A     6
 4:       A     7
 5:       A     8
 6:       A     9
 7:       B     3
 8:       B     4
 9:       B     5
10:       B     6
11:       B     8
```

- Part2

```
> setDT(df)[, .(Visit = setdiff(seq(max(Visit)), Visit)), Subject]
   Subject Visit
1:       A     3
2:       B     3
3:       B     4
4:       B     5
5:       B     6
6:       B     8
```